# eat dinner vs have dinner

Tags: sentence-construction

Are both sentences are correct or only the second one is idiomatic, but the first one must be "They were eating."?

> They were eating their dinner.
>
> They were having their dinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They were eating their dinner.**

- is more precise
- Check this, both are not interchangeable.

  - john won't eat his mashed beans.
  - john won't have his mashed beans.

**They were having their dinner.**

- is more general
- They were having their dinner.

  - Also includes if they drank something while having dinner.
  - they may or may not be just eating dinner.

Conclusion:.
Both are not entirely interchangeable. But could be used interchangeably depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they're both correct, they just use a different word. There shouldn't be anything wrong with that.

Also, "are both sentences correct", not "are both sentences are correct".